# Remove incomplete Anaconda environment, reduce space Anaconda uses

Tags: r, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, environment, virtual-environment

I tried to create a new Anaconda environment in Ubuntu 16.04 without realizing that my computer was quite low on disk space.

Here's the line I ran:

```
conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base
```

The environment did not complete, I received the error:

```
[Errno 28] No space left on device
```

However, some of the packages did download...and it looks like they have reduced the amount of space on my computer.  Even though the environment did not complete successfully, it appears as though the packages downloaded are taking up space.

I thought I would have to delete the incomplete environment to free the space again.

However, when I look at the Anaconda environments, `conda info --envs` the new environment does not appear, so there is nothing for me to delete.  Even when I inspect the folder where Anaconda environments are stored, the half-formed environment is not there also.

Is it possible that the partially downloaded packages are lurking somewhere else on my machine?  Or should they have automatically deleted when the environment did not complete successfully?

If the partial packages are still there, how do I find and delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah! This [post](https://www.cognitivecoder.com/2017/10/25/using-anaconda-with-python-and-running-out-of-disk-space-heres-a-tip-to-quickly-free-up-a-lot-of-space/) has an extremely useful command for cleaning up space that Anaconda is hogging!

```
#Cleanup downloaded libraries (remove tarballs and packages):
conda clean -tp
```

This freed up 3 GB for me in a matter of seconds. Perhaps the partially downloaded packages were still lurking as tarballs that had not been installed yet.

More info on conda clean available [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html).